# SOUNDEX is not working with JPA using JPQL

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, jpql

I have the following JPQL structure with the SOUNDEX expression to perform phonetic spelling matching.

```
StringBuffer nativeQuery = new StringBuffer();
nativeQuery.append("SELECT gr FROM CodeMaster gr WHERE gr.id.grcpy = ?1 AND (SOUNDEX(gr.id.sourcecode) = SOUNDEX('").append(searchValue).append("') OR SOUNDEX(gr.sourcedescription) = SOUNDEX'").append(searchValue).append("'))")
query = getEntityManager().createQuery(nativeQuery.toString());
```

but during the createQuery it gives me the following error.. Please let me know if is any thing i am doing wrong here. If ireplace the **SOUNDEX** with **UPPER** it works fine. Also i ran the query on database results are fetching normally.

> SystemErr R optimum.clinicals.waf.GeneralFailureException:
>   
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: "Encountered
>   "SOUNDEX (" at character 68, but expected: ["(", ")", "*", "+", "-",
>   ".", "/", ":", "<", "<=", "<>", "=", ">", ">=", "?", "ABS", "ALL",
>   "AND", "ANY", "AS", "ASC", "AVG", "BETWEEN", "BOTH", "BY", "CONCAT",
>   "COUNT", "CURRENT_DATE", "CURRENT_TIME", "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP",
>   "DELETE", "DESC", "DISTINCT", "EMPTY", "ESCAPE", "EXISTS", "FETCH",
>   "FROM", "GROUP", "HAVING", "IN", "INDEX", "INNER", "IS", "JOIN",
>   "KEY", "LEADING", "LEFT", "LENGTH", "LIKE", "LOCATE", "LOWER", "MAX",
>   "MEMBER", "MIN", "MOD", "NEW", "NOT", "NULL", "OBJECT", "OF", "OR",
>   "ORDER", "OUTER", "SELECT", "SET", "SIZE", "SOME", "SQRT",
>   "SUBSTRING", "SUM", "TRAILING", "TRIM", "TYPE", "UPDATE", "UPPER",
>   "VALUE", "WHERE", , ,
>   , , , ,
>   , , ]." while parsing
>   JPQL "SELECT i FROM InformationSource i WHERE i.id.companynumber=?1
>   AND (SOUNDEX(i.id.sourcecode) LIKE ?2 OR SOUNDEX(i.sourcedescription)
>   LIKE ?2 ORDER BY i.id.sourcecode". See nested stack trace for original
>   parse error.

Answer (score 0):

As the message says clearly enough `SOUNDEX` is not a valid `JPQL` keyword/function. If you really need to invoke proprietary `SQL` functions then use the `FUNCTION` keyword (if using JPA 2.1). Better still would be to read [some JPQL documentation](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/jpql.html) before just dumping whatever SQL into a JPQL query. JPQL != SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Apache commons Metaphone utils. Those utility classes transform a string in its soundex variant, so you don't have to ask to JPQL this operation, it is not good to use proprietary functions via JPA.